# How come each item gets pushed to all arrays?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I make a grid like this:

```
  let columns = Math.floor(width / new Boid().perceptionRadius)
  let rows = Math.floor(height / new Boid().perceptionRadius)
  let grid = {
    grid: Array(rows).fill(Array(columns).fill([])),
    dimensions: {
      width: (width / rows),
      height: (height / columns)
    }
  }
```

and then I push items to the array like this:

```
flock.forEach((boid)=>{

    let column = Math.floor(this.position.y / grid.dimensions.height),
        row = Math.floor(this.position.x / grid.dimensions.width);

     grid.grid[row][column].push(this)
})
console.log(grid.grid)
```

When I look in the output, every tiem in both row and column contains `flock.length` items, why?

Comment: This fills an array with a bunch of references to a single array: `Array(columns).fill([])`, later when you push to it you are pushing to all of them.

Comment: It's because `Array.prototype.fill`  is not as useful as it might appear.  It uses a shared reference to a single object; so each cell gets the same array.  Just try looping over your rows and columns to initialize each with a new `[ ]`.

Comment: `grid: Array.from(Array(rows), _ => Array.from(Array(cols), _ => []))`

Comment: Right now you're only making three arrays (each call to Array creates one and the `[]` creates one more). You have a grid/rows array which is filled with a bunch of references to a single cols array, which is itself filled with a bunch of references to a single cell array.